# Getting error: NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException while debugging application for AWS S3

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-boot-maven-plugin, aws-s3-client

I am trying to create an application in Intellij using Spring Boot, AWS, Angular. I created an API for uploading video to AWS S3 but facing below errors.
Getting below errors:

```
C:\Users\anuragj\.jdks\openjdk-20.0.1\bin\java.exe -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:4137,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:C:\Users\anuragj\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2023.1\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar=file:/C:/Users/anuragj/AppData/Local/Temp/capture1.props -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\anuragj\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath1805729470.jar com.exprojects.youtubeclone.YoutubeCloneApplication
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:4137', transport: 'socket'
15:17:00.228 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate io.awspring.cloud.autoconfigure.config.parameterstore.ParameterStoreConfigDataLocationResolver [org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolver]
    at org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator.lambda$static$0(Instantiator.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator.instantiate(Instantiator.java:153)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator.instantiate(Instantiator.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator.instantiate(Instantiator.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.<init>(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.<init>(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.createConfigDataLocationResolvers(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.<init>(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:148)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.getConfigDataEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:301)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.exprojects.youtubeclone.YoutubeCloneApplication.main(YoutubeCloneApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/amazon/awssdk/awscore/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3473)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2652)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator.instantiate(Instantiator.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.Instantiator.instantiate(Instantiator.java:150)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:4137', transport: 'socket'
```

I tried all mvn commands - clean, install etc but did not work. Tried deleting ".m2 repo", restarting IDE, changed dependencies.

Expected: Application ran successfully

Please find below POM.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.ex-projects</groupId>
        <artifactId>youtube-clone</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-openfeign-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.505</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.505</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ex-projects</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```